# Eclipse Java formatting: How can I stop wrapping parameters but wrap implements?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I have this code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> parseQuery(String query) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    ...
}
```

which becomes in IntelliJ

```
Map<String, List<String>> parseQuery(String query)
        throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    ...
}
```

but in eclipse:

```
Map<String, List<String>> parseQuery(
        String query
)
  throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException,
  InvocationTargetException {
    ...
}
```

(notice the `String query` in a new line.)
How can I wrap the `throws` part, but not wrap the parameter part (since it is not long enough to be wrapped)?

---

EDIT: I'll share my current settings.
https://gist.github.com/ndac-todoroki/c643336879f6b496a5826407fa69485d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to project properties -> Java Code Style -> Formatter -> Click "Edit..." next to the active profile. Check the "Maximum line width" under "Line Wrapping" if this should be less or equal to 80, increase the value.

By default latest Eclipse built-in profile uses 120. But there's still the old Eclipse 2.1 built-in profile which uses only 80 characters or you may use a custom profile.

**Update**

Wrapping can be configured more fine-grained under "Line Wrapping". After Changing the options for *Parameter* to "Wrap where necessary" and for *throws clause* to "Wrap where necessary" and "Default Indentation" (see the rectangles in the image below) you get exactly the wrapping behaviour you want. Parameters within method declarations are now only wrapped when maximum line width (configuration mentioned above) is reached. If you never want parameters to be wrapped, then select "Do not wrap" for *Parameters* instead.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/rmunge/2c4f2d2cf6c8a4ce24369ebf0849f66f/revisions) you can find an updated version of your configuration file.

[image]

Comment: I checked that value, and it was 120. Changing that to up to 150 didn't correct it either... Actually I'll share the whole preferences, so please take a look at it.

Comment: @Todoroki What happened when you lowered the value to 80 or less as the answer suggests?

Comment: @NomadMaker actually the answer suggests to _raise_ it, but lowering the value does not fix either. There would be an additional newline after `IlligalAccessException,`.

Comment: Thanks @rmunge ! The updated answer solved it all. I wanted to have the parameters all on their own lines when wrapped, so I selected "wrap all elements, every element on a new line" for Parameters, but it also worked fine. Thanks!